# viewDidLoad() and viewDidAppear() called only once?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This is my ViewController (no changes to other files):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("hi from vdl")
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("hi from vda")
    }

}
```

1. I press the triangle in xCode ("Build and then run the current scheme") and get the output:

> hi from vdl 
>   hi from vda

2. Now I move to the home screen, swipe from the left side of the simulator and swipe the app out. Output:

> Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9

3. Now I start the app from the simulator (click on the icon in home screen). App starts but there is no output. Why ? I need to rerun the app from xCode to get the output.

Comment: After app is terminated, it is disconnected from the xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you close the app in simulator, you break the connection with the debugger.

P.S. You didn't call `super` in `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad()` and `viewDidAppear()` work when you get in a VC(ViewController),like present,push,pop,dismiss.

When a VC is presented or pushed to other VC,`viewDidLoad()` and `viewDidAppear()` will work.And when you pop/dismiss a VC,the previous VC shows up which make `viewDidAppear()` work.

But Move to home screen doesn't make effect on the two.

If you want to know when the app will enter the background,use the `func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication)` in `AppDelegate.swift`

Comment: This makes perfect sense but is not directly related to the question, which was why there is no output from viewDidLoad() or viewDidAppear() when I start an app from simulator.

Comment: @bdskfsdk321dsad3 Because you just kill the app.You just disconnet the xcode and simulator.`viewDidLoad()` and `viewDidAppear()` work fine and the output is just there.The only problem is you cannot catch the message from xcode.If you want to see the output,press `Build and then run the current scheme` again to rebuild it so that you can see the message from xcode again.